# solve poisson equation on a circle region

Tags: physics, poisson

Suppose there's a **Poisson equation with circle region and the boundary condition is zero**. I'd like to solve it numerically using **fininte difference method**. However, as far as I konw, finite difference is widely use in renctangular region. So, if I still use finite difference in circle region, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe perform polar change of variables and express Poisson's equation in these polar coordinates. Then the circular region becomes rectangular. Now, try finite differences.